# Assuming that A and B are non-empty, if there is an injective function F : A -> B then there must exist a surjective function g : B -> A

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Either give a counter-example, or a proof.

A question in my proofs review.

From what I understand we must assume each element of A is carried to a unique element of B (i.e. every value of A is associated with a unique value of B when punched into F).

We now must prove (or disprove by use of counter-example) that there always exists a surjective function G that carries B -> A.  Surjectivity (from what I understand) means that EVERY element of A (in this case) has AT LEAST one associated B value in terms of the function G.

Will anybody be kind enough to correct any misunderstandings that I may have?
Also, I can't really figure out where to begin with this question, help needed!

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Idea: (i) if $f(a)=b$, let $g(b)=a$ and (ii) if $c\in B$ is not $f(x)$ for any $x$, let $g(c)$ be any fixed element $a_0$ of $A$.

Comment: So if c is the image of F we can define g as the following:

f^-1(x) if x is an element of c.
Otherwise, let x = x(naught) where x(naught) is any element of b that is not an element of c.

Comment: Don't call a set $c$. And what you propose to call $x_0$ is supposed to be in $A$. The proposed answer is not right.

Comment: Correction: 

C is a subset in B.  x(naught) is in A.
Can we define g(x) as the following: 

f^-1(x), if x is an element of c.
x(naught), if x is not an element of c. 

Is this correct?

Comment: Need to say $C=f(A)$. Better to use variable $y$ for $g$. Need to change the other small $c$.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key on this one is to to realize that, since $F:A \to B$ is injective, we can define an inverse function $F^{-1}$ on $F(A)$, the image of $A$ in $B$.  For every $z \in F(A)$ is the image of *some* $y \in A$, that is, $z = F(y)$ for $y \in A$, and since $F$ is injective there is *exactly one* such $y$.  We set $y = F^{-1}(z)$, *on* $F(A)$, for $z  \in F(A)$; we note that $F^{-1}:F(A) \to A$ is a surjection, since each $y \in A$ satisfies $y = F^{-1}(F(y))$; we define a function $V:B \to A$ by setting $V(z) = F^{-1}(z)$ for $z \in F(A)$, and $V(z) =a$ for *any* $a \in A$ when $z \in B - F(A)$; since $F^{-1}:F(A) \to A$ is surjective, $V: B \to A$ is a surjection from $B$ to $A$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!! ***

Comment: This looks to be the same as my answer, but I suppose both are the same as André Nicolas' comment, as well.

Comment: @Benjamin Dickman:  certainly the essential mathematical content is the same.  Some problems only seem to have one solution!  But I think having multiple "renderings" of.a given argument is a good thing; you never know just what might click for a reader, and one person may connect better than another.  My take on it, in any event.

Comment: True enough. . .

Answer (score 1):

Denoting the injection as $F$: then its inverse, $G$, is a surjection from $F(A) \rightarrow A$.

(Where $F(A) := \{F(a): a \in A\}$ is the image of $A$ after applying $F$ to it.)

Since $A$ is nonempty, we can pick $a \in A$.

Extend the domain of $G$ from $F(A)$ to $B$ (if necessary) by mapping all elements in $B-F(A)$ to $a$.

This (possibly extended) function, $g$, is a surjection $B \rightarrow A$. **QED**.